# Nginx PNG compression

Tags: nginx, png

Is it possible to configure NGINX to compress PNG files it serves. For example I have some PNG files generated by a third party tool and they are uncompressed (do not use PNG compression). I would like to get them compressed before serving them through NGINX. I do not mean gzip, but real PNG compression. Is it even possible ?

Comment: Probably this module will help you https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed

Comment: What do you mean? All PNG images are compressed. Could you post a link to one such "uncompressed" PNG images?

Answer (score 1):

As @Tarun mentioned, Google's pagespeed project could help with that. I have used it in the past with some level of success. However, I would advise against it unless you really optimize NGINX's caching as well. You really don't want to be compressing images on the fly every time your server receives a request. Instead, I would compress the png images before they even get to your server. I personally use kraken.io for this, but there are a zillion great compression tools. Then, you are just compressing them one time and not performing the same compression on the fly every time a visitor requests the image.